# Upgrade from 1.12 to 1.13.1 and 404 pages

Tags: upgrade, ee-1.13, 404-page

we have successfully upgraded Magento from 1.12 to 1.13.1 .

All Modules and everything is working fine except the Category and product pages.
All category and Product pages shows 404 page.

All other links and default pages like login, my account etc etc are working fine.

Any idea what could be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Did you rebuild the url rewrites index after upgrade? Actually you should rebuild all the indexes

Comment: Nope , it says "SCHEDULED". How could i rebuild it Manually?

Comment: I have no experience with EE 1.13, so I don't know then the indexes are 'scheduled' to be rebuild, but I'm sure you have to rebuild them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, be sure to rebuild your indexes via shell

```
php shell/indexer.php reindexall
```

They're set to "Scheduled" in admin, and you can see exactly how that's handled by checking -

```
System->Configuration->(Advanced)Indexing
```

They should be set to "On Save", but experience tells me that you should do it manually anyway.

If that fails, open your database and check that during the upgrade these two tables have been populated -

```
catalog_product_entity_url_key 
catalog_category_entity_url_key
```

If they haven't, then you'll either need to attempt to upgrade again, or populate them manually.

Let us know how you get on.

Comment: Yup, if catalog_product_entity_url_key 
catalog_category_entity_url_key are empty no SEO urls will work with or without reindex.

Comment: i did the manual reindex using shell commend 
php shell/indexer.php reindexall and its works fine now. Thanks

Comment: be careful there are some bugs in magento ee 1.13.1 and url key management ... for ex. when you change the url key of a cat or a prod, or the default sitemap ext. ...

Answer (score 1):

There is a script you will need to run in the shell directory (url_migration_to_1_13.php)

We also had some instructions from Magento (April 2013) to run the following SQL command which cured the 404 page for Home.

DELETE FROM enterprise_url_rewrite WHERE request_path = '';

Comment: On a recent upgrade from 1.12 -> 1.13.0.2 we needed to run this command to finish the upgrade:
drop table catalog_category_entity_url_key; drop table catalog_product_entity_url_key;

Comment: what does it fix ?

Comment: I recently upgrade Magento 1.12 to 1.13.1.0 but i am having some issues with the URL , I do have some products assgin to different category and the url is set to include the category paths in 1.12 version , but when i did upgrade and run the url_migration_to_1.13 , most of the urls are messed up . now its not showing the category path in url and showing some extra -1 at the end or url like  www.abc.com/test-product-1.html . Any idea how can i keep the same url as it was in my old version ? Change of url will cost a lot if i dont get same urls in new version .Any suggestion ?